# This code is not working with console.log but working fine with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

This code is supposed to show a chessboard of 8*8 size and it works fine when I use `document.write` but it doesn't show the same output with `console.log`. Can someone please explain.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var hash = '#';
  var size = 8;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
        document.write("\xa0");
      } else {
        document.write(hash);
      }
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the code with `console.log` to show the problem

Comment: Well, there is no `console.log()` in your code.  That might explain why `console.log()` isn't working?

Comment: Every time you use `console.log`, the output is on a new line. When you use `document.write`, no new line is added, and the HTML rendering would remove them anyway since you need a `<br>` to have one. In the console, you'll also see the HTML tags as you wrote them, since the console does not render HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var hash = '#';
  var size = 8;
  var string="";
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
        string+="\xa0";
      } else {
        string+=hash;
      }
    }
   string+="\n";
   
  }
   console.log(string);
}
```

Comment: superb this is what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

console.log is going to output things to your console.  depending your browser you can open your developer tools and see a console.  This is the preferred method for showing javascript output.

document.write is going to output things directly to the webpage.